# Change install path of MSI setup while repairing

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to repair an installed msi setup with below argument:

```
msiexec /f "msipath"
```

It is repairing properly. But while repairing i need to change its install path too. I tried this argument `msiexec /f "msipath" INSTALLDIR="path"` 
But this is not working.

Whether it is possible to change the install path of an msi while repairing it?. If possible means, please share the exact argument.

Comment: It's not possible.  Directories are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. For a component to be moved, it must be uninstalled and then reinstalled. (Repair just replaces resources in their original locations.) Consider this note on [MsiSetTargetPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370392.aspx):

> Do not attempt to configure the target path if the components using those paths are already installed for the current user or for a different user. Check the ProductState property before calling MsiSetTargetPath to determine if the product containing this component is installed.

Thus you typically have to remove and reinstall the entire package. A major upgrade can be a good way to accomplish that, depending on your other needs.